# Subdomain is on different EC2 instance, SSL is giving "Your connection is not private" error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have example.com, test.example.com and example.org.

example.com and example.org are hosted on 2 different EC2 instances. I want example.org content to be shown at test.example.com.

This is what I have done -

1. Installed letsencrypt ssl certificate for data.example.com (earlier only example.com and example.org had SSL vie LE).
2. Added A record of example.org IP in the DNS of example.com so test.example.com now points to example.org IP.

Now when I open https://test.example.com, it is showing "your connection is not private" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you mistiped some example.org ...

Answer (score 0):

You need a certificate signed for the domain you're using it on.

If http://test.example.org is using example.com's SSL certificate, then yes, this is not OK and every browser will complain about it.

In your web server, you should set up a virtual host with its own SSL certificate for every domain server that needs one.

Look for the files in /etc/apache2/sites-available that correspond to each domain and make sure that:

1. The configuration file corresponds to an SSL site (i.e. uses port 443 and sets SSL certificates properties for this site)
2. Each site is configured to use its corresponding SSL certificate
3. There's a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled pointing to the configuration file on sites-available
4. You've restarted Apache after making any modification to these files

Comment: Hi, I already created a virtual host file. I can access http://test.example.com but can't access https://test.example.com. I added A record with "test" as host and value as server IP, but https://test.example.com is showing content of example.com. Here is my vhost file for test.example.com, do I need to edit it for ssl? https://pastebin.com/wmLG0E2w

Comment: That file is for http, not https. Look at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl or some similar file to get how it has to be configured. Mine is at https://pastebin.com/yqhVqRu9

Comment: I have default-ssl.conf in sites-available and homer-le-ssl.conf in sites-enabled which has following data https://pastebin.com/xp4fp8Xt. But I have read that I shouldn't edit sites-enabled file, so how to enter ssl details for test.example.com?

Comment: Yo have to use different SSL certificates for every domain/site. Check your configuration in that homer-le-ssl.conf file. site-enabled dir files are usually symbolic links to files in sites-available directory - that way it gets very easy to enable or disable sites, by just creating and deleting symbolic links and restarting Apache.